# Is it possible to use JavaScript generated text from Django templates using the"with" templatetag

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, django-templates, geodjango

I am using the following [W3schools JavaScript code](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error) to generate latitude and longitude results in my Django templates:

I was wondering if it was possible to use The results spat by the JavaScript to my django variables using the `{% with ... %}` template tag

Below is my user.profile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)        
    age = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    member_since = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lon = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326, default='SRID=4326;POINT(0.0 0.0)')
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Comment: You have to post it either using a form or ajax call.

Comment: @NourChawich The problem with adding form  is that users will have to add their own `lats` `lon` details and click submit. That won't be too practical. How exactly will I use the Ajax call

Comment: It could be a hidden form that is auto-filled with the javascript call and submitted using ajax. You need to check Django docs on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function in which AJAX call goes to one of your URL.
In AJAX call you need to send lat and lon values and save them to Database.
Call this AJAX function on document/page load.

You can either make a POST or a GET call using AJAX.

```
var element = $("#element-id")    

$.ajax({
url : $(element).attr("data-url"),
data : {
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : $(element).siblings("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']" ).val(),
    "alt":lat,
    "lon": lon
},
method: "POST",
dataType : "json",
success : function (returned_data) {            
    // display data 
}});
```

If you are sending a GET call, ignore the csrf token.

Where element is hidden field/link/button in HTML with data-url attribute.

Comment: I am checking this as soon as I verify it works I will add a check-mark to your answer I have up voted it for now